# magnto load css only for url checkout/#payment

Tags: payment

i want to load css file only if URL is checkout/#payment

can I add do via layout XML it tried but it seem not workig

Answer (score 0):

Each page has its own class.
Catch it and write css
[image]

Or add css in xml like:

```
<head>
        <css src="css/fontawesome/all.min.css" />
</head>
```